# Как сделать это на PowerShell?

Tags: bash, powershell

Всем привет! Нужна помощь в переписывании однострочного скрипта. :)

```
#!/bin/bash

grep -vwE "ДнейОтсрочки" "Doc_2020-01.xml" > 01_new.xml
```

Этот скрипт ищет в файле Doc_2020-01.xml строку "ДнейОтсрочки" и удаляет её (удаляется полностью  строка файла, а не только искомое вхождение).

Результат записывается (выводится) в файл 01_new.xml
Особенность: искомая строка и xml-файл в кодировке UTF-8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Да почти также, только вместо `grep` `Select-String`. Основное отличие в том, что пайпы в Powershell передают объекты, а не просто байты, и по-умолчанию `Select-String` выдает объекты класса `Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.MatchInfo`. Чтобы он начал выдавать просто строчки необходимо добавить параметр `-Raw`

```
Select-String -NotMatch -Pattern "ДнейОтсрочки" -Path "./Doc_2020-01.xml" -Raw > "./01_new.xml"
```

В версиях Powershell до 7 параметра -Raw не было, и там было бы необходимо дополнительно обработать выхлоп, оставив только строки:

```
Select-String -NotMatch -Pattern "ДнейОтсрочки" -Path "./Doc_2020-01.xml" | ForEach-Object { $_.Line } > "./01_new.xml"
```

Comment: Спасибо! Всё работает!

Answer (score 1):

Примерно так будет выглядеть команда:

```
Select-String -NotMatch 'ДнейОтсрочки' 'E:\Doc_2020-01.xml' | Set-Content 'e:\01_new.xml'
```

`Select-String` - аналог `grep`
`-NoMatch` - аналог `-v`
`Set-Content` записывает stdout в файл

Comment: Спасибо! Работает, только в выходном файле каждая строка дополняется:
E:\Doc_2020-01.xml:1<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
E:\Doc_2020-01.xml:2<Exch:_UD xmlns:Exch="http://www.test.ru/V1/COPERUD/" xmlns:core=
...
...
E:\Doc_2020-01.xml:NNNN</Exch:_UD>